# How to accept higher limits in PHP arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, limits

I'm running a simple script to randomize values of an array, it works perfectly, but:

```
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25");
rand_keys = array_rand(input, 15);

echo input[rand_keys[0]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[1]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[2]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[3]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[4]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[5]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[6]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[7]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[8]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[9]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[10]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[11]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[12]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[13]]. "\n";

echo input[rand_keys[14]]. "\n";
```

Here very well, but up there where present the numbers, the variables of the array that will be used to be shuffled, the values ​​in the array, I cannot do too big, because it seems that there is an input limit in the matrix that PHP recognizes the same line, but if I break line, the script stops running, no longer works!

Is because I need some 1500 entries of these, instead of 1 to 25, need 1 to 1500, but here, when to writing, there comes a time, her pro number 350 or so letters editor change color, all I write starting this part on, is appearing standard black, as if writing had a common text in gedit, that is, cease to be part of the PHP code! And if I break line, the color remains normal, but the code does not accept line break in this part of the code:`$ input = array ( "1", "2", "3"`. How do I my PHP server recognize more variables in arrays?

PHP is my PHP Version 5.4.16, I'm running Centos 7 64x. Using webmin.

Comment: Please post in English, no one able to understand what you are saying?

Comment: Please!! excuse me, already posted in English, I hope you can help me. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean, is that while you are adding to your array, eventually your single line is so long that your IDE stops highlighting syntax, then you can break up the code onto new lines, by hitting return right after a comma like such:

```
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
          "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
          "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it is just that, my arrays is so great that one point for being interpreted by my IDE, then I must break the line, but this is the big problem, when I break just like you made, the code stops working when I comment the lines below the script back to work perfectly, it is as if the array can't be more than one line! but I can not just stay with the top line, I need the entire code. the line would have to be much larger than the limit, else break that line in a special way for the code does not break down and stop working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should take a look to php's yield keyword or to array range, then you would be able to reduce your code to an iterative version.

take a look to the php manual ([yield](http://php.net/manual/es/language.generators.syntax.php),[range](http://php.net/manual/es/function.range.php))

Comment: the solution of any problem is the manual of all languages, when someone resorts to help professionals is to reduce the burden of work or gaining time to not have to spend weeks looking for a solution for own account, in my case it is almost impossible, my English is poor case has not noted, I just speak language of Indians, Portuguese. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an unknown size for array size you can try this code below.

```
<?php
$input = array();
$range = 1500;
for ($i = 1; $i<= $range; $i++) {
$input[] = $i;
}
//print_r($input);
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 15);
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
echo $input[$rand_keys[$i]]. "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in all we had, and it was that I had already tried of course, was the solution of a simple line break after the comma when you reach the limit that support IDE, but my problem is that in the midst of many values, not be realized one dubs quotes between a value and another, and it broke the code, so when I add the following lines, not work because the second was this repeated quotes, then breaks the script, eg 2 "," 3 " "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "" 9 "as here before the 9, that was mistake because my script did not accept other lines, since only the first is free this error, and when commenting on the low the code worked removed repeating quotes and returned to work, thanks to everyone and especially you unexpectedError that made me insist on the question of a break line, and does not accept that does not work and why review slower the giant list of values, Nao was lazy my friends, not great level of inattention, it is because they really are many values, numeric tangle of letting anyone dizzy. Thank you all. was of great help, it was delaying me a lot, Best Regards to all of SOF.